# Inserting Char value into SQL table

Tags: sql, insert, char

I created a SQL table an enforced check constraints on it, but now when I try to insert data I get an error message.

```
create table BranchTel
(
    BrRegNo varchar(10) REFERENCES Branch(BrRegNo), 
    TelNo char(12)
    PRIMARY KEY(BrRegNo)
)
ALTER TABLE BranchTel Add Constraint BranchTelTelNo
Check(TelNo LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Insert statement

```
insert into BranchTel values('BG-205','940112571963')
```

Error message

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "BranchTelTelNo". The conflict occurred in database "StudentDetails", table "dbo.BranchTel", column 'TelNo'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   Insert statement
>   insert into BranchTel values('BG-205','94-011-2571963')
>   Error message
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check constraint is 14 characters long (you need to count the `-` as well), while the field size is 12.

Additionally, `940112571963` does not conform to the pattern `xx-xxx-xxxxxxx` you have defined in your check constraint.

You need to change the field size to 14 and when inserting make sure the dashes are in the right place:

```
insert into BranchTel values('BG-205','94-011-2571963')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert statement insert into BranchTel values('BG-205','94-011-2571963') Error message String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.
```

Here the value `94-011-2571963` length is greater than 12 which obviously violates the check constraint.

Comment: Does it count the   -   as well. I have tried inserting 10 digits also with the - but still it wont get inserted Should we put the - in the statement or only write the number